# Routing Error - custom controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes, has-many-through

I have a has many through association.

Firms have many Users through Follows.
I want Users to be able to Follow Firms. - I am using Devise for the users.

I have the following action in my firms controller.

```
def follow
  @firm.users << current_user
end
```

in my routes.rb

```
resources :firms do
 post :follow, on: :member
end
```

and in my firms view

```
<%= link_to "Follow", follow_firm_path(@firm), method: :post %>
```

However when I keep getting the following Routing Error in the browser

```
No route matches {:action=>"follow", :controller=>"firms"}
```

Rake Routes confirms the following

```
follow_firm POST   /firms/:id/follow(.:format)   firms#follow
```

Any ideas what the problem may be?

Many thanks

---

**Edit:** Controller code

```
class FirmsController < ApplicationController 


before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index] 

def index 
  @firm_names = Firm.all.map &:name 
  direction = params[:direction] 
  direction ||= "ASC" 
  @firms = Firm.order("name #{direction}")   
  respond_to do |format| 
   format.html # index.html.erb 
   format.js 
  end 
end 

def follow 
 @firm.users << current_user 
end
```

I am using the follow action in a partial in the index view.

Comment: Why are you using 'on: :member' and 'method: :post'. The correct way is ':on => :member' and ':method => :post'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything looks good and this should work perfectly. Except that I see a typo in the following line

```
<%= link_to "Follow", follow_firm_path(@firm), method: :post %>
```

after the :method there should an **=>** not a **:** . this will make the link a get request not a post request, that might be the issue, try using a simple link and replace post will get in your routes.rb just to test if the issue is arising due to this.

you can also test route methods from the console

```
rails c
app.follow_firm_path(2)
```

I noticed you also have an error in your routes, there should be an => not a : after :on

```
resources :firms do
 post :follow, :on => member
end
```

Comment: ah, i thought that a : after was synonymous with hash rocket after a symbol. Have changed all of that syntax to : and => and... the terminal seems to agree with us the route does exist:

"/firms/2/follow" However the browser is still stating: No route matches {:action=>"follow", :controller=>"firms"}

Comment: did you try using get both in your routes.rb and in your link.

`resources :firms do
 get :follow, :on => member
end`

`<%= link_to "Follow", follow_firm_path(@firm) %>`

Comment: yeh I tried it with GET on both. Could it be an issue with my controller action?

Comment: @RMcNairn: Please edit the question to add more information, not answers. I've done this for you in this case.

Comment: @RMcNaim: Please also edit the question to add the updated lines in your routes.rb and your view.

Comment: I shall do, I have however managed to find the problem, two days of headache, and it is now working perfectly i think it was my inconsistent use of : shorthand! I have made everything consistent and it has done the trick.

Thank you so much for you help you chaps are lifesavers!

Answer (score 0):

You should define methods like this...

```
  resources :firms do
    collection
      post :follow, on: :member
    end
  end
```

I think if this method does not create anything its type should be get.

Try it

Comment: Hi kasif.ali,
I gave that a try and this came up as an error:

    can't use member outside resource(s) scope.

When I pass it a slightly modified version of your suggestion:

     resources :firms do
       collection do
        post :follow, on: :member
       end
      end.

I get the same

    No route matches {:action=>"follow", :controller=>"firms"}

In the event that I change it to GET, I get the above error on Scope.